# How can I accept "subdirectories" as parameters in PHP

Tags: php, apache, http

I am currently working on remaking a closed source API that is no longer maintained. I am lucky enough to still be able to use the API for the time being, but I'm not sure how much longer it will be available.

Essentially, the API returns info about games in JSON format, and the application uses this data.

An example API call is below:

```
/api/updates/game/version
```

From what I can tell, they don't just have a file for each version, I believe it processes all "subdirectories" as a get request(I may be wrong about how it does it)

My question is how can I make all subdirectories from one folder on go to a PHP file, and provide information about the call.

The last, and most difficult thing is, how can I do this without redirects. Because of how the application was made, it does not follow redirects, and will error out at 301(As I found out while trying to use index.php for each version folder).

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for 'rewrite rules'

Comment: This question cannot be answered without code analysis. You need to get more familiar with topics like *URL rewriting* and *friendly URL's* in PHP. Then you'll be able to find how it's done in this case. Also you will know what exactly you want to ask us in your next question(s)

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on the [Front Controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and use it together with a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router). This way, you'll have one single entry point in your application and can easily define the URL's in your code. All paths will be virtual so there's not URL-to-folders-structure correlation. This is how most frameworks do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### .htaccess

You have to do some edits to your `.htaccess`. What you want is one PHP file that receives all requests to the directory inside. Put this into your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /api/
    RewriteRule ^api\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /api/api.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will point all requests to the same file: `/api/api.php`

Example:

/api/game/xy/ -> `/api/api.php`
/api/game/xy/version -> `/api/api.php`
/api/hello -> `/api/api.php`

### /api/api.php

Now, in your `/api/api.php`, get the requested path with  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

In my example below, I added a `str_replace`, because on Windows the paths are including `\` instead of `/`.

```
<?php
// /api/api.php
$requestURI = str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```